# time complexity of this approach

Tags: java, python, time, time-complexity

So I am reading two files and storing each line in two different lists respectively. Now I have to check if a string in the first list is present in the 2nd list.

By normal comparison this will take O(n^2)

But using a graph based data structure like -

File1_visited[string] = True

File2_visited[string] = True.

I can check if both are true, then the string is present in both the files. This makes it O(n).

Is there any other approach I can reduce the time complexity and Is my understanding correct?

Example Scenario -

File1-

Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4

File2 -

Text5
Text7
Text1
Text2

Comparing these two files.

Comment: Something major your analysis misses is, "What is the time complexity of building and accessing the graph structure?" A simple, fairly efficient way would be to load both files into hash sets and then check for an intersection. That's pretty similar to your approach, but it uses standard structures that are very efficient to create and access. How big are your files?

Comment: Assuming maximum is 1000 lines. Also is my understanding correct regarding the two approaches. I thought of the hash set but is not the same as 2nd approach as it might need to go through each file once

Comment: If your data set is only 1000 lines, why do you care about O(n)?  Big O Notation is for really, really large sets of numbers/calculations.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: For 1000 lines maximum, the growth complexity of your algorithm doesn't matter. That's 1 million comparisons even in your simple O(n^2) algorithm, which is child's play for modern machinery. Unless you have to compare thousands of files, you're better off doing something simple to implement and not worrying about the performance. Just make sure you load the whole file into memory before doing any processing and you'll be fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that any time you spend developing should ultimately save more time than it took to develop. ;) If it's faster to write a simple algorithm and just let it run and you don't have to do it over and over, then just do it fast and let it run.

Comment: I actually wanted have a gist of these algorithms so I can make sure my thinking process is in the right direction or not ...

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you went from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`. You might want to look into the space complexity as well, you would have to store the graph for one of them while for the other one  you would use less space. A HashMap looks ideal for this situation if you do not care about memory, or any other array if it's easier to implement.

Comment: Well, technically `O(n+m)`, and that assumes `HashMap`, but OP said *"using a graph based data structure"*, which means `TreeMap`, and that would be `O((n+m)⋅log(n))`, assuming first file (`n`) is loaded into the map, and second file (`m`) is only used to check the map, rather than creating a second map, like OP actually said.